# Inbound ICMP Cloudformation Security Group Rule Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I simply want to create an inbound security rule in my Cloudformation template that looks like this:
[image]

Everything I try - several suggestions from here, in fact - all give me this result:
[image]

What am I missing? This is my current attempt:

```
PrivateSecurityGroupIngressA:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  Properties:
    GroupId: !Ref PrivateSecurityGroup
    IpProtocol: icmp
    FromPort: 8
    ToPort: -1
    Description: Allow Inbound ICMP
    CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
    PrivateSecurityGroupIngressA:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
        Properties:
            GroupId: !GetAtt PrivateSecurityGroup.GroupId
            IpProtocol: icmp
            FromPort: -1
            ToPort: -1
            Description: Allow Inbound ICMP
            CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: I thought I tried all iterations of "-1" for the to and from ports, but that was it! FYI, I don't need the .GroupID after the name of my Security Group